# How do I reset Mobile Chrome on android so I can request mic access

Tags: android, microphone, mobile-chrome

I'm Have a samsung S5 that I'm testing microphone access on, and I accidentally hit "don't allow" once. Now chrome thinks that it should automatically reject the mic access on that domain, which makes it impossible to test. How do I reset chrome so I can gain mic access again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gain access to your domain by going to:

`Settings>Content Settings>Website Settings>your.domain.com>Voice`

from your mobile browser.

And by the way this is how you do it on a desktop chrome.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

For mobile Chrome, select the options dropdown, and tap on the info icon between refresh and favourite. This brings up the site information, tap on Site Settings to change specific permission settings like mic or camera access.